# How can I get all the triples from Wikidata, for all the proper nouns?

Tags: sparql, wikidata, triples

My end aim is to get all the Wikidata triples in the form
`{SubjectLabel, PredicateLabel, ObjectLabel}`, preferable in CSV format, for all the proper nouns, such as People, Cities, Countries, Books, etc.

I tried querying for all subjects having P31 ("instance of"), property on SPARQL interface, but that results in timeout due to the number of results.

What would you suggest would be the fastest way of getting this done. I don't seem to find any solution for the same. Is there any existing way for this?

Comment: That won't work with the public SPARQL endpoint, the resultset is too large. Download the RDF dump and process it locally on your machine.

Comment: So do you think, if I set up the SparQL on a local server, it wont result in timeout? Setting up on local server is given here https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_query_service/User_Manual#Standalone_service

Comment: If you use a local server, you can usually control the query timeout value. Indeed, public services have a lower value to remain responsive as it is a shared service.